# Conditonally inject dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection, autofac

I am injecting a dependency in an action method of an ASP.NET MVC controller .

Scenario: I want to use interface in action method of an ASP.NET MVC controller. This interface is implemented by 2 classes. For example modelA and modelB both implement `interfaceA`. At runtime when user changes the value in dropdown according to the value of dropdown  dependency injection should determine if it should inject modelA or modelB.

Also I am not sure is DI is the only solution, or do other solutions exist? Or factory patter not sure .

Comment: This isn't a good use for dependency injection. There's no easy way to connect the result of the drop down with the DI container. Better to just inject both and have the class select according to the route or URL parameter.

Comment: Thanks I think it would work. I will try .
Can we put common login somewhere instead of writing in many action method ?
Also one thing i forget to mention ModelA and ModelB reside in diffrent assembly.
suppose when dropdown value 1 i have to make instance of modelA else ModelB
Like 
Public ActionResule MehtodName(InterfaceA inter)
{
//Should i go with the route values ??
}

Comment: You can register them with your DI container and inject them into your Controller class, e.g. `class MyController(ModelA a, ModelB b)` and then save them in `private readonly` fields, each action method can then use them. Or if they have a common interface you could inject an `IEnumerable<IModel>` and then pick which one to use based on some metadata on the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a factory pattern:

```
public interface InterfaceAFactory
{
    InterfaceA Create(int dropDownValue);
}

public class AFactory : InterfaceAFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;
    public AFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public InterfaceA Create(int dropDownValue)
    {
        if(dropDownValue > 0)
            return _container.GetInstance<ModelA>();

        _container.GetInstance<ModelB>();
    }
}
```

(or simply inject the required dependencies instead of the container)
and then simply

```
private readonly InterfaceAFactory _interfaceAFactory;

public MvcController(InterfaceAFactory interfaceAFactory)
{
    _interfaceAFactory = interfaceAFactory;
}

public void DropDownValueChanged(int dropDownValue)
{
    var model = _interfaceAFactory.Create(dropDownValue);
}
```

I've used StructureMap but you can adapt this to AutoFac (registering the instances, injecting a container and resolving the instance).

Comment: Would you give me example with ActionMethod in controller .
I am  putting dependancy to incomming model not in constructor.
like Public ActionResult ActionName (IMyModelInterface obj)